# Why does the migrate dialog only list Arduino Meta?

Tags: discussion

> This question is probably due to my lack of understanding of the inner workings of the review queue code, and the procedures associated with it. This question also *may* not be SE Arduino specific, in which case I would be happy for it to be migrated to SE Meta.

If you are reviewing *Close Votes*, and think that a question is off-topic and should be migrated, you click on **Close**, and are presented with:

> [image: Why should this question be closed dialog]

Then click on "off-topic because...", and you are presented with:

> [image: Off topic dialog]

Then clicking on "...belongs to another site...", gives you:

> [image: Migration dialog]

Why is only Meta listed? Should there not be either a list of other sites (i.e. SO, Programming, EE, ...) or a picker or a text box?

There can't be many cases where questions need to be migrated to Meta. I have seen one or two, but there are more off-topics that could be moved to regular SE sites.

In such a case, is the only recourse, for suggesting a migration, to click the flag link (which is not available in the review stage, but only in the regular view)?

---

My question arose, when reviewing a [question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/21747/understanding-the-contents-of-a-library-in-c) with seemed to have very little, if anything to do with Arduino, and it was in the Close Votes review queue. After having thoroughly read the answers to [When should an Arduino programming question be moved to Stack Overflow?](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29/when-should-an-arduino-programming-question-be-moved-to-stack-overflow) I now see, especially as Nick's answer has given the question more of an Arduino context, that it should actually remain on SE Arduino, as it will, indeed be helpful for others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is because we are "only" a Beta site. Once we graduate, I think more migrating options become available.

As a moderator, I can migrate to other sites, and have done in some cases. I usually ask their moderators first, and quite often they decline to accept them. However migration **does** happen.

I think there is some rule that Beta sites don't get to migrate to other sites. I'm not quite sure why such a rule exists (it would seem more logical for it to be the other way).

Comment: Even on SO, the community can only migrate to meta, superuser, tex, dba, and stats. I believe the SE team is the ones who enable very common migration paths.

Comment: I have just found the same question asked on SE Robotics Meta: [Closing a question - only option for another site is Robotics Meta](http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/1287/closing-a-question-only-option-for-another-site-is-robotics-meta)